# SAS date transformation

Tags: sas

I have character date 'yyyymmdd' and would like to transform it to date9. 
e.g. '20141120' to '20nov2014'

```
data _null_;
 format yyyymmdd $8.;

 yyyymmdd = '20141120';

 filedate = input(input(yyyymmdd, yymmdd8.), date9.);

 call symput('filedate', filedate);
run;

%put &filedate.;
```

While i cannot achieve by above code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there... simply change the outer `input()` to a `put()`.

```
data _null_;
 format yyyymmdd $8.;

 yyyymmdd = '20141120';

 filedate = put(input(yyyymmdd, yymmdd8.), date9.);

 call symput('filedate', filedate);
run;

%put &filedate.;
```